# Javascript window.scrollBy speeds up

Tags: javascript

I have a project I'm working on with a site that receives information and displays it in a table.  If the table is larger than the screen, the page will automatically scroll down, and when it hits the bottom, back up, and repeat, repeat, up and down.

The issue I'm having is that every time I send a chunk of data to the site, the speed of the scrollBy increases.  Every refresh scroll incrementally faster, up and down.

Here is the code:

```
window.onload = function() {

   ...
        buildHeader(event);
        buildTable(event);
  };




function buildTable(event) {
 ...

  if((+tableHeight) > window.innerHeight){

     pageScroll();
  }

}





 var scrollDirection = 1;
 function pageScroll() {
   window.scrollBy(0,scrollDirection); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
   scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',50); // scrolls every 50 milliseconds

   if ( (window.scrollY === 0) || (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >=                   document.body.offsetHeight) {
    scrollDirection = -1*scrollDirection;
   }

}
```

I would like to know why each time the page is sent information the speed increases.  Isit necessary to cancel an occurring scrollBy before calling it again?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. If you call scrollby twice, it will scroll twice. You have a self-calling timeout, which means that it would repeatedly call the function. The timeout is async, and won't be cancelled just because something changed.

Luckily, `setTimeout` returns an ID that you can pass to `clearTimeout()`.

So you can do something like this:

```
var currentTimeout;

function buildTable(event) {...

    if ((+tableHeight) > window.innerHeight) {
        window.clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
        pageScroll();
    }

}

function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0, scrollDirection); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    currentTimeout = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 50); // scrolls every 50 milliseconds

    if ((window.scrollY === 0) || (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        scrollDirection = -1 * scrollDirection;
    }
}
```

Here's a simpler example to demonstrate the behavior. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jpjyzdb7/)**.

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  I have confirmed it works with my site.  Alternatively, I was able to also solve the problem by adding a boolean, setting as true when the first pageScroll() is called, and checking it each time the page refreshes.  However, your solution seems safer in the long run.